# How to use a variable data as a scope variable in jstl

Tags: java, jstl, el

I want to dynamically create variable names in java el. 
The problem is that the second line returns sessionScope.saved_activity as a string instead of data.

```
<c:set var="savedKey" value="sessionScope.saved_${entry.key}" />

<td> <input type="text" name="${entry.key}" value="${savedKey}"> </td>
```

How can I retrieve the data from a string in el ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the sole key name and then use that as a dynamic key of the `${sessionScope}` with the brace notation.

```xml
<c:set var="savedKeyName" value="saved_${entry.key}" />
<input type="text" name="${entry.key}" value="${sessionScope[savedKeyName]}">
```

Comment: scope="session" in the `c:set`?

Comment: @Bozho: not necessary for a dynamic key. Would only possibly interfere with other pages which are requested concurrently in the same session. @ Horatiu: you're welcome.

Comment: It's not necessary. You should also not do it. Page scope is perfectly fine.